# Should I use kubeadm reset every time I reboot my master (or worker) node of kuberenetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I am new in DevOps. Recently I bought two raspberry pi devices and setup one as master and the another as worker node. When I reboot the device the docker containers (api server etc.) don't up.

What should to do in this case ?
Should I use `kubeadm reset` and `kubeadm init` each and every time I reboot device (server in case of production) and **re configure the whole cluster** ?

I am attaching screenshot here:

[journalctl -u kubelet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdbDI.png)

[journalctl -u kubelet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtiD9.png)

Comment: The short version is "for sure: no" but no one can help you without posting why your containers don't start after reboot; please consider [editing your post](https://serverfault.com/posts/1022937/edit) to include that detail

Comment: If the docker container get upped then will the cluster automatically be configured ? I don't know actually whether I should manually configure or not each time I reboot the server.

Comment: Does the IP address of the master node change when you reboot?

Comment: No, it is fixed @HelloWorld

Comment: Can you provide logs from kubelet? `journalctl -u kubelet` and also check if docker is running after reboot `systemctl status docker`.

Comment: I have edited my question and added screenshot of `journalctl -u kubelet`. Please kindly see the errors. And yes,  `docker`  is running @HelloWorld

Comment: Lines in golang logging that begin with `F` are fatal, as one can see in that _error message_ saying you must disable swap, or otherwise tell kubelet you're prepared to deal with the mess that can result from leaving it enabled

Answer (score 0):

In Kubelet logs you can see this line:

> failed to run Kubelet: running with swap on is not supported.

Followed by `Main process exited`.

To resolve the issue you need to disable swap. Check [this stackoverflow answer](https://serverfault.com/a/684792/545145) for more info on how to do it if you don't know.